# Text box disabling in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, html-helper

while typing  contents in one `textbox(TextBox0)`, same conents are automatically copying in to the another 3 `textboxes(TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3)`.It is working propertly.

My problem is :
    Some times  I have to change the contents of `TextBox1 or TextBox2  or TextBox3` .At that moment ,if i type anything in the main `textbox((TextBox0)` the contents changed in the above text boxes are changing automaticllay and loses the  edited contents in the corresponding textboxes.If i disable or set the readonly property in the TextBox0,i cant type anything in that.

I want  After editing the contents in the `TextBox1 or TextBox2  or TextBox3`, no need to automatically copy the contents typing in the `Textbox0`. How it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply this can be done by setting flag value on each text Box function .Eg

```
    <input id="TextBox1" type="text" name="TextBox1"  onChange="fun_TextBox1()">
    <input type="TextBox0" id ="TextBox0" name="TextBox0" onKeyUp="funTextBox0()"> 
<script>
var text1=0 ;

function fun_TextBox1() {
     text1 = 1;

}
function funTextBox0() {
    var n1 = document.getElementById('TextBox0');
    var n2 = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
  if (text1  != 1) n2.value = n1.value;

}
</script>
```